# System of three equations in three variable having degree 1,2&3 respectively.

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Can we solve a system of three equations in three variable , with the equations having degree 1,2 and 3 ???
Consider
$$P(x,y,z)=a $$
$$Q(x,y,z)=b $$
$$R(x,y,z)=c $$
where $P,Q,R $ are polynomials of degree 1, 2 and 3 respectively.
How many solutions can be found ??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You can eliminate one variable from the linear equation, then the problem reduces to a system of two equations in two unknowns of degrees $2$ and $3$ respectively. You can eliminate variables between polynomial equations using [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), which in this case will give a polynomial equation of degree $6$ in the remaining variable. That's in the general case, of course, if you work with a particular system it's always possible that there may exist shortcuts.